# How serious is this sfdx force:lightning:lint error on Array.from?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, locker-service, lightning-lint-tool

This Lightning Component code appears to work:

```
    var tab = component.get("v.tab");
    var fields = new Set();

    tab.qualifiedFieldApiNames.forEach(function(item) {
        if (item) fields.add(item);
    });
    tab.listQualifiedFieldApiNames.forEach(function(item) {
        if (item) fields.add(item);
    });

    return Array.from(fields);
```

but `sfdx force:lightning:lint` says:

```
error  ecma-intrinsics  Invalid Intrinsic API  
Line:312:16
        return Array.from(fields);
```

What does "error" mean in this report? And if it is advisable to not use `Array.from`, what is the minimum alternate code to convert a set to an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimum alternate code could look like this:

```
var tab = component.get("v.tab");
var fields = new Set(),
    fieldsArray = []; // placeholder array

tab.qualifiedFieldApiNames.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item) fields.add(item);
});
tab.listQualifiedFieldApiNames.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item) fields.add(item);
});

// convert to array
fields.forEach(function(item){ fieldsArray.push(item); });

return fieldsArray;
```

As far as why the linter is complaining about the `Array.from()` function - that is unclear. It's definitely part of the ECMAScript spec [ [Array.from()](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.from) ] which is what that linter is [documented to be checking against](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/cli_rules_ecma_intrinsic.htm).

Comment: Duh - now feeling pretty stupid about how obvious the alternate code is... but thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The Lightning linter complains about `Array.from` because this array method is part of ES6 but the linter validates against ES5 only.

I would not recommend to use it because it is not supported by Internet Explorer.
See this link for compatibility and polyfill: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Comment: If I could accept 2 answers I would... We have IE customers so avoiding code for this sort of reason is important to us. Thank-you.

Answer (score 3):

Use `[].slice.call(fields)`

Taken from: https://github.com/addyosmani/es6-equivalents-in-es5

Note that this **won't** convert NodeList and similar array-like collections.